# Add some blue points like the red ones

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I use this code to generate `nbp` red points. I can drag them and it will show the coordinates:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pts = Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nbp, 2}], 
   dynamicPts}, 
  dynamicPts = 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
    Dynamic@Graphics[{Black, Circle[], Red, Point[pts]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> 300]];
  Row[{dynamicPts, 
    Dynamic[Grid[MapIndexed[{Row[#2], Style[#1, Red]} &, pts], 
      Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}]]}]], {{nbp, 5, 
   "Number of Points"}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

[image: "nbp" red points]

It works, and now i want to add `nbz` blue points like this:

[image: "nbp" red points + "nbz" blue points]

Here with the code:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{ptsRed, ptsBlue, dynamicPts}, 
  ptsRed = Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nbp, 2}];
  ptsBlue = Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nbz, 2}];
  dynamicPts = 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[Join[ptsRed, ptsBlue]], 
    Dynamic@Graphics[{Black, Circle[], Red, Point[ptsRed], Blue, 
       Point[ptsBlue]}, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
      ImageSize -> 300]];
  Column[{dynamicPts, 
    Grid[{{Style["Red Points", Red], 
       Style["Blue Points", Blue]}, {Grid[
        MapIndexed[{Row[{"Point ", #2[[1]]}], Style[#1, Red]} &, 
         ptsRed], Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}], 
       Grid[MapIndexed[{Row[{"Point ", #2[[1]]}], Style[#1, Blue]} &, 
         ptsBlue], Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}]}}, 
     Spacings -> {2, 2}]}]], {{nbp, 5, "Number of Red Points"}, 1, 20,
   1}, {{nbz, 5, "Number of Blue Points"}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

But when I want to drag the point, I get an error:

[image: Messages]

It seems I cannot use `Join[ptsRed, ptsBlue]`.

Answer (score -1):

Both of them are working for me. Maybe you need to use clear and run them again.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```